# need to get filter TextValuePair array

Tags: c#

I have two list one each contain some same fields data, I would like to remove duplicate items in retrun a TextValuePair array. but the problem is if userids more than one it remove last one in foreach and retrun other in users.

Here my code

```
      public TextValuePair[] FindAllUserByNotThisId(int id)
        {
            TextValuePair[] users=null;
            var userids = _uow.UserInGroups.GetAll().Where(x => x.GroupId ==  id).ToList().Select(s=>s.UserId);
            foreach (var userid in userids)
            {
               users=  _uow.Users.GetAll().Where(x => x.UserId != userid).ToList()
                       .Select(
                           s =>
                           new TextValuePair
                           {
                               Text = s.UserName,
                               Value = s.UserId.ToString()
                           })
                       .ToArray();
            }
            return users;
        }
```

if userids count is 3 then it remove each duplicate id but at end it remove only 3 id and other two will show in users final result like below:-

userids

```
userid
1
2
3
```

users

```
userid username
1        a
2        b
3        c
4        d
```

it returns me first two also

```
userid username
1       a
2       b
4       d
```

but i wants only

```
userid username
4       d
```

please help..

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think your problem is the foreach and the overwriting of the `users`collection. Try this:

```
public TextValuePair[] FindAllUserByNotThisId(int id)
        {
            TextValuePair[] users=null;
            var userids = _uow.UserInGroups.GetAll().Where(x => x.GroupId ==  id).ToList().Select(s=>s.UserId);

               users=  _uow.Users.GetAll().Where(x => !userids.Contains(x.UserId)).ToList()
                       .Select(
                           s =>
                           new TextValuePair
                           {
                               Text = s.UserName,
                               Value = s.UserId.ToString()
                           })
                       .ToArray();
            return users;
        }
```

Without the `foreach` loop and the overwriting of `users` collection we know now that the `users`collection would not be modified after the where filter.
And using the contains we could evaluate the whole `usersid` without using a loop.

Comment: @mukesh That's why i use `userids` instead of `userid` in the answer. The unique difference between your implementation and my answer is that i get rid of the foreach and use `userids` (the collection of userids you want to filter) directly in the evaluation (with a `Contains` instead of a `==` operator). Did I understand you wrong?

Comment: hey thanks i didn't read you answer properly and used my own by get idea of not in operator in sql. I see your answer now properly and its similar like mine. Thanks i voted up.:)

Comment: @mukesh Glad to help @mukesh! If this solved you problem please mark it as answer to help future user's that read this post. Thanks for the voteup by the way ^^